# Moving objects at specyfic time in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've got problem with my App.
I have to make multithread App in JavaFX. 
I want to have 5 objects called "excavators" which would go up (moveUp) at 00:05:00 for half an hour (my specific time) and „moveDown” at 00:35:00 for half an hour too. That means between 00:00:00-00:04:59 and 01:05:00-24:00:00 they would „stay()” in the centre of Window. To sum it up my problem is : I want to move my „excavators” for one „hour” from centre of Window.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;


public class Main extends Application {
StackPane root = new StackPane();
Time time;
Text t1 = new Text();
Image excavatorImage = new Image("resources/excavator.png");
Image smallVehicleImage = new Image("resources/small.png");
Image largeVehicleImage = new Image("resources/large.png");
Excavators excavators;
ImageView imageOfExcavator1 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator2 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator3 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator4 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator5 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle1 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle2 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle3 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle4 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle5 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle6 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle7 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle8 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle9 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle10 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle1 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle2 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle3 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle4 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle5 = new ImageView();


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00FF00");
    primaryStage.setTitle("My App");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
    checkTime();
    createExcavators();

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void checkTime() {
    time = new Time(this);
    time.start();
    root.getChildren().add(t1);
}

public void updateTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    String time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    t1.setTranslateX(-450);
    t1.setTranslateY(-380);
    Platform.runLater(() -> t1.setText(time));
}

public void createExcavators() {
    imageOfExcavator1.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator2.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator3.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator4.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator5.setImage(excavatorImage);
    root.getChildren().add(imageOfExcavator1);
    root.getChildren().add(imageOfExcavator2);
    root.getChildren().add(imageOfExcavator3);
    root.getChildren().add(imageOfExcavator4);
    root.getChildren().add(imageOfExcavator5);
}

public void moveExcavator1(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator1.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator1.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator2(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator2.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator2.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator3(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator3.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator3.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator4(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator4.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator4.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator5(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator5.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator5.setTranslateY(y);
}
}
```

The second class:

```
public class Time extends Thread {

public int hour = 0;
public int minute = 0;
public int second = 0;
Main main;
Excavators excavators = new Excavators(main);

Time(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public void run() {
    for (; ; ) {
        try {
            second++;
            if (second == 60) {
                second = 0;
                minute++;
            }
            if (minute == 60) {
                minute = 0;
                hour++;
            }
            if (hour == 24) {
                hour = 0;
            }
            if (hour == 0 && minute == 5 && second == 0) {
            }
            setTime(hour, minute, second);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}


public void setTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    Excavators excavators = new Excavators(main);
    excavators.start();
    System.out.println(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    main.updateTime(h, m, s);
    excavators.getTime(h, m, s);
}
}
```

Third class:

```
public class Excavators extends Thread {
Main main;
int x = 0;
int y = -450;

Excavators(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}


public void run() {
    for (; ; ) {
        try {
            System.out.println(x + "a" + y);
            Thread.sleep(40);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public void setCoordinates1(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator1(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates2(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator2(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates3(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator3(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates4(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator4(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates5(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator5(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates() {
    setCoordinates1(-400, y);
    setCoordinates2(-200, y);
    setCoordinates3(0, y);
    setCoordinates4(200, y);
    setCoordinates5(400, y);
}

public void moveDown() {
    y = y + 2;
    setCoordinates();
}

public void moveUp() {
    y = y + 2;
    setCoordinates();
}

public void stay() {
    y = 0;
    setCoordinates();
}

public void getTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    if (h == 0 && m >= 5 && m < 35) {
        moveUp();
    } else if ((h == 0 && m >= 35) || (h == 1 && m < 5)) {
        moveDown();
    } else {
        stay();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you again. I'm not too sure what exactly is the problem you are facing, but you can try changing all the `setTranslateX(x)` and `setTranslateY(y)` to `relocate(x, y)`.

Comment: Unfortunately relocate doesn't work in that case.
The point is that I would like my objects to move up non-stop for '30 minutes' and then down again for '30 minutes'. I tried to do it in many ways and unfortunately I am not able to create the effect of continuous moving of objects.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you are seeing, and why do you think whatever you're seeing is wrong.  Your question only stated briefly the desired outcomes, without telling us why you think it's not working now.

Comment: This in turn. This code works, but moving objects when you call the moveUp () / moveDown () method is performed only once (y = 2 or y = -2).
However, I would like the objects to change their coordinate y (eg 100 times) at 00:05:00 and I would like them to keep coming up to the top edge of the window and keep moving up until they disappear over the top edge of the window. Punctually at 00:35:00 the objects begin to move down (the same number of times as have moved up) all the time in a similar way.

Comment: Then at 1:05:00 all objects return to the original location where they were before 00:05:00. Objects should then stay at position y = 0 and wait until 23 hours elapse and again at 00:05:00 they will start to move up to 1:05 return again to their place and so on and on.
The biggest problem for me at this point is the creation of a mechanism for moving objects, and a simultaneous constant change of time within the application.

Comment: After reading your problem in detail, I realized my solution is not what you are looking for. I do want to point out that It appears you are trying to move `Nodes` around in a `StackPane`.